# Increasing sequence of index sets

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $I_1 \subset I_2 \subset \cdots$ are increasing index sets, each of which is countable. Set $I = \cup_n I_n$. Then do we have $$\sum_{k \in I} a_k = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k \in I_n} a_k?$$ Seems to me that this would be yes, but I am not sure exactly. I believe that one could use some analysis to deduce this, but the notation itself is a bit confusing for me. I know I probably did not formulate this in the best way, but I hope the question is clear.

Comment: Check the continuity of measure from left.

Comment: @Mr.Proof: Could you clarify a bit please?

Comment: How are you defining the sum over an index set? Are there negative values in $a_k$?

Comment: @ScottHahn: I am taking the sum over nonnegative values of $a_k$. Basically, $I$ is a union of these increasing sets, and I was wondering if there is a way to break the whole sum over $I$ as just the limit of the sums over $I_n$.

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264184/proving-that-one-can-split-a-convergent-series-into-a-countably-sum-of-subser?noredirect=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you define the sum over an index set and whether you allow negative values in $a_k$.

Consider $I_1 = \{-1,1\}$ 
$I_2 = \{-2,-1,1,2\}$ 
$I_3 = \{-3,-2,-1,1,2,3\}$ 
$a_k= 1$ if $k>0$, $-1$ if $k<0$

Clearly, the sum over any particular  index set $I_n$ is 0. Hence, the limit of the sum over index set $I_n$ is also 0. However, the lefthand side, the infinite sum over $I$, is undefined.

EDIT: The above was written before the clarification that $a_k$ nonnegative.

If we have that $a_k$ is nonnegative, then the equality holds. Define the sum over an index set as the supremum of the sum over all possible finite subsets: [Notation of a sum over an arbitrary index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4281681/notation-of-a-sum-over-an-arbitrary-index).

Clearly, LHS $\leq$ RHS. Consider any finite sum on the LHS, then we can pick $n$ big enough so that all the elements included in that finite sum are also included in RHS. So, since the finite sum of LHS is $\leq$ than RHS, the sup of the finite sum of LHS is also $\leq$ than RHS.

It remains to show that LHS $\geq$ RHS. Consider the sums over each index set $I_n$ on the RHS, call these $S_n$. Pick $N$ big enough so that RHS$-S_N < \epsilon$. Pick enough elements (but still finite) from the first index set so that it sums to $S_1 - \epsilon/2^1$. Pick enough elements from the second index set so that it sums to $S_2 - \epsilon/2^2$. Repeat until we arrive at $S_N$.

So, LHS + $\epsilon + \epsilon \geq$ RHS. But $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, so LHS $\geq$ RHS, which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: Thank you for answering anyway!

Comment: Updated the answer